# Restart a computer using function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I was learning about function pointers in C when I came across a program that restarts the computer upon execution.

```
void (*f) (void);
f=(void (*)(void) MK_FP(0xFFFF,0x0000);
f();
```

The (void (*)(void)) portion wasn't in the original text provided, and  I had to make this addition to get the code to compile. How does this work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That might work on a machine running DOS; it probably wouldn't work on a machine running Windows, and definitely wouldn't work on a machine running Unix.  Are you running DOS?  And Turbo C++ 3.0 is not so much 'old school' as too old to still be at school (it was released in 1991!).

Comment: Where is MK_FP defined?

Comment: Joel Cornett, it is defined in <dos.h>, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: Actually I'm running on window :( All my friends who are good at coding have moved on to Codeblock and so on, when I use things like near and far pointers, they just don't know what the heck that I'm writing about. So I'm pretty sure it's old school

Comment: Why are you writing MS-DOS programs in 2014? Your friends don't know what you're talking about because you're talking about obsolete technology.

Answer (score 5):

About programs that manually construct function pointers from numeric literals and call them, the C standard says only that *the behavior is undefined*.  That means you can't expect the program to behave the same way from computer to computer, or even from run to run on the same computer.

About *this particular* program, we can make an educated guess about what it was meant to do and under what circumstances it will actually do that:

The original operating system for the original IBM PC, commonly known as MS-DOS, started executing code at the segmented address `FFFF:0000` upon power-on.  (Some sources say `F000:FFF0` instead -- for reasons too tedious to get into here, that is the *same physical address*, but expressed a different way and possibly behaving differently depending on what code is at that location.)  Because this OS was so bare-bones, jumping to that location after the machine was up and running would perform an approximation to a warm reboot.

On the assumption that your `MK_FP` macro constructs a segmented function pointer from segment and offset values, then, *when your program is executed on an IBM PC running MS-DOS*, it jumps to `FFFF:0000` and performs an approximation to a warm reboot.

On a more modern operating system (including all current OSes for the descendants of the IBM PC) this program is guaranteed *not* to reboot the computer, because unprivileged user-mode programs are not *allowed* to reboot the computer.  Moreover, the `MK_FP()` operation itself doesn't make sense in a modern 32- or 64-bit user mode program, because they run in flat address spaces.  The code may compile, but it almost certainly winds up calling an address that has no memory mapped to it, so I would expect the program to crash.  But the rest of the OS will just keep on going like nothing happened.  If you ran the program inside a DOS emulator, it might reboot the *emulator*, but again, the rest of the OS will just keep on going.

It *is* possible to write a program that reboots a modern OS -- indeed, you already have at least one such program on your computer, or you'd have no way of rebooting it short of the physical power switch! -- but it has to ask the kernel nicely, using a special system call (Unix-family: [`reboot(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=reboot&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE); Windows: [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and it has to be running with special privileges or the call will fail.

That said, a jump to `FFFF:0000` plus a bunch of ancillary chicken-waving *is* one of the low-level operations that current versions of Linux may use to trigger a reboot on x86-based machines.  It's only tried if several other things fail, but it's in there.  See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L484 for an outline of the overall procedure, and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.S for the code that actually executes the jump to `FFFF:0000` after dropping back to "real" (16-bit segmented) mode.

Comment: Neat find. I too would have expected a more "sophisticated" approach for linux to trigger a warm boot.

Comment: @Dogbert I looked again and I was mistaken - ACPI, EFI, and a legacy keyboard-controller-based technique are tried first.  (Gosh, IBM stacked a lot of miscellaneous functions on the keyboard controller, didn't they?)  (Also, I'm seriously unimpressed with the degree to which Linux has turned into spaghetti since I last looked at its guts in any detail.  Which was... 1998.  I'm old.)

Comment: @DangManhTruong I'm not sure why you would *want* to write 16-bit real-mode DOS programs anymore?  But regardless, I hope I was some help to you.

Answer (score 1):

The code is attempting to jump to the address where x86 CPUs start executing at power-on, aka the "Power On Reset Vector" ([source](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/bios/)).

Answer (score 1):

This is a system dependent (ie: non-portable) approach to restarting the machine. What is the intended OS for this program to run on? Is it DOS (I'm assuming). Try running it inside a virtual machine and find out.

If you want this to work on other platforms, you'll need to write some platform specific stuff, like so:

```
#ifdef __linux__
  system("shutdown -P now");
#elif _WIN32
  #if (WINVER == NTDDI_WIN7) // Windows 7
    system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");
  #endif
  #if ((WINVER <= NTDDI_WINXPSP3) && (WINVER >= NTDDI_WINXP)) // Windows XP
    system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown -s");
  #endif
#else
  #error System not recognized
#endif
```

Comment: Or you could call `reboot` or `ExitWindowsEx`.