# request password program in C

Tags: c

I am reading a program that requests a password written by C. But there is one line I do not understand is :

```
if(!OK){
 printf("\nWrong password!"); getch();
 f = MK_FP(0xFFFF,0x0000); f(); // this line I don't know
}
```

while f is pointer of function `void far (*f)(void)`. is anyone can explain thank you

Comment: post complete code to help you better

Comment: And what does `MK_FP` do? On what operating system? On what hardware?

Comment: On what operating system? What computer? What compiler? What headers? I guess that `MK_FP` would be some macro, perhaps building some function pointer.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `MK_FP`.

Comment: Perhaps use [getpass(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) or [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Standard C does not have any password reading ability... You need some OS or some library!

Comment: Look at [THIS](http://members.tripod.com/vitaly_filatov/ng/tc/tc_000.193.html). It init `f` to a specific address location, where, I guess, is stored a function that do something.

Comment: They don't show the implementation of MK_FP. they said it is a function of DOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart a computer using function pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387105/restart-a-computer-using-function-pointers-in-c)

Comment: While your question is correctly formatted; you didn't do any research before posting your question. A simple search on MK_FP(0xFFFF,0x0000) would have got you at least 2 posts on SO alone...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This lines were used to reboot a PC from the BIOS (MS-DOS).

```
MK_FP(0xFFFF,0x0000);
```

construct a *far* pointer (32 bits at the time) and returns it as a pointer to function. Then `f` is executed at that address, rebooting the PC.

It wouldn't work today on modern OSes.

[This program](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/14974-how-to-warm-or-cold-boot-computer) uses it.

Comment: By the way, why it wouldn't work today, and what is difference between [this](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/14974-how-to-warm-or-cold-boot-computer) and that?

Comment: This address used to be the startup address of the system, when it is switched on, or a warm boot when called from a running program. This wouldn't work in, eg., Windows now, because 1) the OS wouldn't let you call that address directly 2) systems changed and, even on 32 bits PCs, that physical address may no more correspond to the "boot" memory segment .